Spinlock functions generating error in xv6 - how to fix "Implicit declaration of function"?
I am currently trying to run a test program in xv6 (downloaded directly from https://github.com/mit-pdos/xv6-public), through WSL. It looks like this:
#include "types.h"
#include "stat.h"
#include "user.h"
#include "spinlock.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
struct spinlock lock;
    initlock(&lock, "lock");

    int x1 = getreadcount();
    int rc = fork();

    int total = 0;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
        char buf[100];
        acquire(&lock);
        (void) read(4, buf, 1);
        release(&lock);
    }

    if (rc > 0) {
        (void) wait();
        int x2 = getreadcount();
        total += (x2 - x1);
        printf(1, "%d\n", total);
    }
    exit();

I put the lock in order to guarantee that the test works correctly, avoiding concurrency problems. But every time I run "make qemu-gdb" (on Ubuntu) it gives error messages:  error: implicit declaration of function ‘initlock’... for initlock, acquire and release. I don't know what exactly is wrong with it. The "spinlock.h" header file doesn't contain the declaration of the functions, but this seems to be the rule for xv6, as they also doesn't appear in the other versions of it. Could someone help?
I've tried to put the "initlock", "acquire" and "release" declarations in the spinlock header file, but it only changes the error to "undefined reference to `initlock'", for each one of the functions. Is it something to do with the Makefile?

The prototypes appear to be in defs.h


The "spinlock.h" header file doesn't contain the declaration of the functions

Simply grepping the function names you're missing in the xv6 source would show the declarations you need are in defs.h.

... changes the error to "undefined reference to `initlock'", for each one of the functions

xv6 is a kernel, it doesn't seem designed to be linked into userspace executables.
You either need to

make your code part of xv6, build it all together, and run it under qemu, or
build a library (.a or whatever) containing the xv6 code you want, and then link your executable with that


Well I did make my code part of xv6, it's in the same directory, and I put in the "uprogs" of Makefile, and I ran it under qemu.
